# Cassandra Timestamp Default Now

Tags: cassandra, timestamp

Is it possible to have a timestamp column in a table with the default value of now, such that only the other fields are introduced?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, There is no way to set default value in cassandra.**

You must provide value or use `toUnixTimestamp(now())` when inserting.

Example :

```
CREATE TABLE sample_times (
    a int, 
    b timestamp, 
    c timeuuid, 
    d bigint, 
    PRIMARY KEY (a,b,c,d)
);
```

Example Insert :

```
INSERT INTO sample_times (a,b,c,d) VALUES (1, toUnixTimestamp(now()), 50554d6e-29bb-11e5-b345-feff819cdc9f, 10);
```